# Get the default upstream remote & branch for "git push"

Tags: git

I've been looking at .git/config, but is there a quick way to get this on the command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check for the default remote upstream remote and branch type the following on the command line:

```
git remote -v
```

If you need to see the remote branches at the same time [note this is very verbose]:

```
git remote show origin
```

This will tell you which upstream remotes are available, which ones are being tracked, etc.

Comment: hmm, it only seems to show the remote (i.e. origin url)... is there a way to show the branch as well?

Comment: @khoomeister updated my answer with a little bit more information buddy

Comment: Actually `git branch -vv` seems to be the best alternative, although slightly verbose.  Thanks for your effort!